# Weak solution of a parabolic equation when initial and boundary conditions are inconsistent

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider the parabolic equation
$$
u_t = u_{xx},
$$
$$
u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0,
$$
$$
u(x,0) = 1.
$$

Initial and boundary conditions are inconsistent but a weak solution exists.
It belongs to $C([0,T];L^2(0,1)]\cap L^2(0,T,H^1_0(0,1))$.

What this weak solution looks like? Does this solution satisfy the boundary conditions? (Computations has demonstrated that the solution decreases from $1$ to $0$ and it does not equal to $0$ on the boundary.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual Fourier series method shows that a solution is given by
$$u(x,t) = \sum_{n=1,3,5,\dots} \frac{2}{\pi n} e^{-n^2 \pi^2 t} \sin(n \pi x).$$
You can check that this satisfies the boundary and initial conditions in the following senses: it extends continuously to $([0,1] \times (0,\infty)) \cup ((0,1) \times \{0\})$, and the extension equals 0 on $\{0,1\} \times (0,\infty)$ and equals 1 on $(0,1) \times \{0\}$.  It does not extend continuously to $\{0,1\} \times \{0\}$.

It's instructive to sum a bunch of terms of this series and graph the resulting approximation.

Comment: Thank you very much!
What means that the solution extends or does not extend continuously?

Comment: I think that there is $4/\pi n$ instead of $2/\pi n$.

Comment: @jokersobak: For a continuous function $u$ on a set $A$, we say $u$ extends continuously to $B \supset A$ if there is a continuous function $v$ on $B$ with $u=v$ on $A$.